# Can 触る mean 'to handle'?

Tags: meaning

> アメリカのハワイ州ホノルル市では１０月から、道を渡っているときに、スマートフォンやコンピューターなどを見たり**触ったり**することが禁止になります。
>   In Honolulu in the American state of Hawaii, from October, looking at and *touching* smart phones while crossing the road will be prohibited.
>   アメリカではほとんどの州で、車を運転しながらスマートフォンを**触る**ことが禁止になっています。
>   In America, in most states, *touching* smart phones while driving has been prohibited.

If the standard translation of 'to touch/feel' is used for 触る in these sentences then they sound a bit weird. I think in this context 'to handle' would be a better translation, but I haven't seen this translation in dictionaries.

To what extent, if any, can 触る be used to mean 'handle'? Could you please give some other examples so I can get a feel for its use?

Comment: I think they mean "touch" as in "use" a smartphone. So they're being literal, but you can understand what they mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, 触る can mean to interact/use devices in general. Some examples:

- 一日中ゲームを触っていても飽きない。
- (スマホ売り場で) 触っていいですか？／どうぞ触ってみてください。
- 彼は趣味でギターを触っています。
- うちのおじいちゃんはタイプライターが触れるよ。
- 板前の修行中なので、少しでも長く包丁に触るようにしている。

Answer (score 2):

> > アメリカのハワイ州ホノルル市では１０月から、道を渡っているときに、スマートフォンやコンピューターなどを見たり**触ったり**することが禁止になります。
> >     In Honolulu in the American state of Hawaii, from October, looking at and *touching* smart phones while crossing the road will be prohibited.
> >     アメリカではほとんどの州で、車を運転しながらスマートフォンを**触る**ことが禁止になっています。
> >     In America, in most states, *touching* smart phones while driving has been prohibited.
>
> If the standard translation of 'to touch/feel' is used for 触る in these sentences then they sound a bit weird. I think in this context 'to handle' would be a better translation, but I haven't seen this translation in dictionaries.

I feel the same way. 携帯{けいたい}を触{さわ}る and 'touching cellphones' are a little too conversational to my ears. I prefer 扱｛あつか｝う or 使用｛しよう｝する in place of 見たり触ったり. Well, however, it seems they use 触る in news casting as well. I wonder if they have concerns that the expressions like（携帯電話｛けいたいでんわ｝などを）扱う is taken to be used for stores selling them and 使用する can be taken as actually use the functions such as sending messages, but then I think people are doing something ***using*** the phone all the same.